# How to extract all the axis labels in an powerpoint chart

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I want to extract all the xAxis label
But so far, my method below can only extract the first value on the Range of X Values

Can anyone advise how can I modify the following code to extract every values in the x-axis labels please.

```
Sub Extract_Xvalues()
Dim sh As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim chtnow As Chart

Dim x As Integer
Dim z As Integer
 
 Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
 Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
 Dim xlworksheet As Excel.worksheet
 
 Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
 Set xlworksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
 xlApp.Visible = True
 
 Set chtnow = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart
  
  xlWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = chtnow.SeriesCollection(1).XValues

End Sub
```

Thanks Much

Answer (score 0):

The `XValues` [is an array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.xvalues) so it's need to resize the range to fit all the values:

```
xlWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(1, chtnow.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Count).Value = chtnow.SeriesCollection(1).XValues
```

*(not tested)*

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Pointed me the right direction. However, this line doesn't work. It worked after I changed chtnow.SeriesCollection(1).Count  inside RESIZE to chtnow.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Count.

Comment: Combined the code in the answer with your additions for correctness